# Subquery with multiple columns in where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

**I have** a table `message` containing 4 main columns :

- `id` : Message's id.
- `interlocutor_id` : The interlocutor's id.
- `timestamp` : the timestamp the message has been sent.
- `expiration` : the timestamp of when the message will expire. If the value is below the current timestamp, it is expired.

**I wish** to get all last messages from each interlocutor (even if they expired), and I also wish all non expired messages (even if they are not the last).

**I tried** this query but then I understood that i cannot make a subquery with multiple columns:

```
SELECT * FROM message 
WHERE  (expiration > 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') 
OR  (id IN (SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) FROM message GROUP BY interlocutor_id) )
```

How should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you intend:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE (m.expiration > 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') OR
      m.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp)
                     FROM message m2
                     WHERE m2.interlocutor_id = m.interlocutor_id
                    );
```

Also, when you say `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`, do you mean something like `datetime('now', 'localtime')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your query works great, but I don't know why. It should be able to include unwished messages in a case where the message is not the last, and has expired (so it is an unwished message), but there is another message from another interlocutor, which is his last and has the exact same timestamp, shouldn't it? I don't know why it does not include such message (I have tested it).

Comment: I did not know there was a sql method to get the current timestamp. But yes i meant it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be by joining to a subquery. Create a subquery that returns the max date for each interlocutor_id and left join it.

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM message M
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT interlocutor_id, MAX(timestamp) ts FROM message GROUP BY interlocutor_id) LastTime 
    on LastTime.interlocutor_id = M.interlocutor_id AND m.timestamp = Lasttime.ts
WHERE  (expiration > 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') 
OR  LastTime.id is not null
```

Alternately you might like to look at EXISTS rather than a Join to look at a subquery, depending on your data this may perform better.